# How to adjust image size when printing in Rails with JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to allow people to click on print to print off an image on the page (where there are multiple images). I can get it to print but it's two pages and shows the left half of the image.

Here's the ERB:

```
<a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('<%= image_path('image.jpg', size: "90x90") %>'); return false;">PRINT</a>
```

Here's the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ImagetoPrint(source) {
return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
        "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
        "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
        "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
        "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
}
function PrintImage(source) {
Pagelink = "about:blank";
var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
pwa.document.open();
pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(source));
pwa.document.close();
}
</script>
```

The size in the ERB doesn't work. I've tried applying a class with max-height/max-width as well and nothing is changing. I've also used image_url instead of image_path. Neither are affecting it.

So is there a way to change the size of an image within an image_path/image_url?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer the underlying question of changing the image size using a different image with a smaller size works.